# Transforming set of arbitrary intervals into set of continuous intervals, where possible

Tags: algorithm, intervals

I have a practical situation, where I need to minimize amount of data.

Let's say I'm given a set of intervals of normal numbers.
e.g. N1 = {(0,1],(1,2],(3,4]};
I would like to minimize this set to:
N2 = {(0,2],(3,4]};

So basically what I need is to combine multiple small intervals into continuous intervals, where it is possible.

Is there any clever/efficient algorithms for doings this? Because I would like to avoid inefficient for-each-ing.

*If this problem have some wide-known name, please name it in the comments.

Comment: why inefficient? Wouldn't one simple loop O(n) suffice? Assuming they are sorted, if not, then sort first and get O(nlogn).

Comment: Not sorted. I'm hopefully looking for something better, than O(nlogn).

Answer (score 2):

This is a [sweep-line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm).

- Split the intervals into start and end points.
- Sort the points.
- Let count = 0.
- Iterate through the points:

  - Whenever you encounter an end point:

    - Decrement the count.
    - If the count = 0, record this point.
  - Whenever you encounter a start point.

    - If the count = 0, record this point.
    - Increment the count.

As a technical note, when sorting, if both a start point and an end point have the same value, put the start point first, otherwise you may record that as a gap, as opposed to a continuous interval.

Example:

```
(0,1],(1,2],(3,4]

Split    0 start, 1 start, 1 end, 2 end, 3 start, 4 end
Count       1        2        1     0        1      0
Record      (0      N/A      N/A    2]      (3      4]
```

Getting the recorded values gives us `{(0,2], (3,4]}`.